# conditional disposing of objects using DI framework (Ninject)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2, ninject.web.mvc

I have the following code

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonoly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public MyService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}

//This code is used by web client
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) 
{
    kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>();
    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
}
```

I have a web and windows service client both use the "MyService" class. I want to dispose the "unit of work" at the end of HTTP request if the client is web, where as if the client is a windows service, I want to dispose the unit of work after every database call. how to achieve that? can I add an extra flag to the MyService constructor, to identify the client, but then how to modify the above code to pass a hardcoded value to that parameter when mapping the concrete types to the interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have some sort of `MyServiceRunner` in yourr Windows service that calls your `MyService`. This class is Windows service specific and this would be the place to explicitly control the lifetime of the `IUnitOfWork`. Or you can write a decorator for `MyService` that controls the unit of work.

A few things to note. Although you can reuse the `IUnitOfWork` on a per-web-request basis, DO NOT `Commit` the unit of work at the end of the web request, but explicitly do this after a service (succesfully) executed. Since the scope of your `IUnitOfWork` is very different in the Windows Service, you probably need some explicit code or explicit registration to handle this. However, make sure that your `MyService` is oblivious to this: It shouldn't need to care.

If you have many services that you want to call in the Windows Service, you might want to think about applying the command/handler pattern for handling business logic. You can read more about it [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).